# How do I get the closest property change before a given point?

Tags: search, text-properties, overlays

How can I get the previous-or-equal single property change for a given property? For example, assume `AAA`, `BBB`, and `CCC` below have different `face`s.

```
AAABBBCCC
```

Here is the return value that I would like to get for each position:

```
AAABBBCCC
111444777
```

Contrast to what `previous-single-char-property-change` returns:

```
AAABBBCCC
111144477
```

Essentially, the problem is that `(previous-single-char-property-change (point-max) 'face)` returns `4` instead of `7`. I thought I could just use `(previous-single-char-property-change (1+ (point) 'face)` instead, but that breaks on `(point-max)`, unfortunately.

How can I achieve get the previous-or-equal single char property change, taking into account the starting position?

Here is some code to reproduce the example:

```
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test*")
  (erase-buffer)
  (insert "AAABBBCCC")
  (mapc #'delete-overlay (overlays-in (point-min) (point-max)))
  (overlay-put (make-overlay 1 4) 'face '(:background "red"))
  (overlay-put (make-overlay 4 7) 'face '(:background "blue"))
  (overlay-put (make-overlay 7 10) 'face '(:background "green"))
  (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer)))
```

Some background: for a major mode that I'm writing I need to read information from the overlay (if any) that precedes (and does not cover) the current point.

Comment: If `point-max` is the only place where you have a problem, can't you just make your own version of the function that does what you want and treats `(eq (point) (point-max))` as a special case?

Comment: The function appears to have changed in the master branch, but I'm not sure when that came about -- here are the arguments I see in the help buffer:  `(previous-single-char-property-change POSITION PROP &optional OBJECT LIMIT)`

Comment: @lawlist: I see these arguments too.

Comment: @nispio: I could; it doesn't look very pretty, though. Do you want to make this an answer? I'll certainly upvote it, and I'll accept it if nothing else comes along.

Comment: In my package [faceup](https://github.com/Lindydancer/faceup) (an extension to `ert` for testing `font-lock` rules) I had the same problem (but for forward searches). Effectively, the function `faceup-next-property-change` returns `point-min` if 1) nil was passed as the start position and 2) there were relevant text properties on the first character. Otherwise, the real next position was returned.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```el
(defun last-prop-change (prop &optional limit)
  (let ((pos+1 (min (1+ (point)) (point-max))))
    (previous-single-char-property-change pos+1 prop nil limit)))
```

---

**Update**

The following is a more complete wrapper than the one given above in that it supports arbitrary positions within `object`.

```el
;; source: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/23989/93
(defun last-single-char-property-change (position prop &optional object limit)
  "Position of the last change of a property before or at POSITION.

This function is just a thin wrapper around
`previous-single-char-property-change', with the POSITION
argument effectively becoming POSITION+1.  This means that if the
PROP property changes at POSITION, then POSITION is returned."
  (let (pos+1)
    (cond
     ((stringp object)
      (setq pos+1 (min (1+ position) (1- (length object)))))
     ((bufferp object)
      (with-current-buffer object
        (setq pos+1 (min (1+ position) (point-max)))))
     (t
      (setq pos+1 (min (1+ position) (point-max)))))
    (previous-single-char-property-change pos+1 prop object limit)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Will leave the question open a little longer to see if we get other suggestions.

Comment: If that's what OP wants then it can be described as the last change before position point+1.

Comment: After testing this a bit more, I think you need one more check, to see if the property is already set on `(point-max)`. Otherwise this returns the wrong result on `point-max`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the previous single property change for a given property?

You got it.

There is no `face` property change at position 7. The previous property change for `face` is at position 4.

(It's not clear why you want what you say you want, or even what it means.  This really smells like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821). Maybe say what you are really trying to do?)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to rewind to the previous property change. Which doesn't work at position 4.

Comment: I've updated the example.

Comment: In other words: as you say, there is a change at position 4. But asking for the previous change at position 4 does not return 4.

Comment: Asking for the **previous** change at position 4 correctly returns the position of the **previous** change, which is position 1. It's still not clear what you are really asking for. Apparently you are *not* wanting the **previous** change at position 4...

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding :/ Maybe "previous-or-equal" would be clearer? I'm asking for a function that implements the xample that I gave in the original post.

Comment: Yep, =<. No problem.